# Printing Perfect Numbers between 1-100 using Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, perfect-numbers

I don't know what is the problem with my code. It should print all the perfect numbers between 1-100. I tried with nested for-loop, do while loop and for-loop. However, the code seems to be incorrect.

```
class CompProject1
{

    public static void main()

    {

        int num, sum=0;

        int i;

        for(num=1; num<100; num++)

        {

           for(int j = 1; j<=num ; j++)

           {

               if(num%j==0)

               {

                   sum = sum+j;

                }

            }

           if(sum==num)

           {

             System.out.println(sum);  

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem statement? Because you might be able to get away with `System.out.println("6, 28");`.

Comment: @jsheeran, come on dude, it's a programming assignment

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to :

```
public static void main(String[] s1) throws Exception {
    int num, sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (num = 1; num < 100; num++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= num - 1; j++) {   // change made here
            if (num % j == 0) {
                sum = sum + j;
            }
        }
        if (sum == num) {
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        sum = 0;                              // change made here
    }

}
```

Key takeaways:

1. Reset `sum` to 0 once done with inner iteration
2. In your *inner* `for-loop` you need to check if till `num - 1` and not `num` because every number is divisible by itself

Comment: He should actually iterate to num/2, your answer is fine for fixing the problem he faced, but not so good in case of optimization

Comment: What optimization do *you* need to print perfect numbers from 1-100? It wouldn't make any difference. Your down-vote is ridiculous.

Comment: How can you even know it's mine? The thing is not even about optimization, it's about correct math-model.

Comment: What if he's gonna need to evaluate the values of first 1.000.000 numbers?

Comment: 1. Pretty obvious that you down-voted it (Since there was a comment at the very same time) 2. Why should I care if its till 1,000,000? Question clearly states 1 - 100. This is also **not** a question on performance.

Comment: 2. Coz you're smart dude (I hope so), so you should have seen this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

1) you definitely need to reset your sum variable for every iteration, so you should do `int sum = 0;` in every loop.

2) you need to iterate while `j <= num/2;`!

3) consider using Java 8, I'll write some sample here for you.

See my example here, this is so beautiful:

```
public class PerfectNumbersDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(1, 100)
        .filter(PerfectNumbersDemo::isPerfect)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private static boolean isPerfect(int number) {
    return number == IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number / 2)
        .filter(i -> number % i == 0)
        .sum();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- `sum = 0` with every loop iteration
- iterate until `< num` and not `<= num`

Here's the fixed code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

int sum;
for(int num = 1; num < 100; num++) {

    sum = 0;

    for(int j = 1; j< num; j++) {
        if(num % j == 0) {
            sum += j;
        }
    }

    if(sum == num) {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

}

Output:

> 6
>   28

Comment: THis is the correct answer and should be marked as such

Comment: why r u guys initializing sum outside the loop since int has cache? looks ugly...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an assignment or homework question. You are meant to solve this by yourself and not ask it to the people on Stack overflow.

However, what you are looking for has an answer [here](https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-check-given-number-perfect-number/). Beware! This code prints if the input number is perfect number or not but does not print all the numbers below 100 that  could be perfect numbers. That is your homework.

Answer (score 0):

So, your code have some minor problems and I will try to pinpoint them out.

1.First of all your sum variable should be inside the first for loop
2. The limit upto which the second loop will run will be `j<num` not `j<=num` because, for the perfect number, the number itself shouldn't be counted in the sum.

You code will look like this.

I don't know what is the problem with my code. It should print all the perfect numbers between 1-100. I tried with nested for-loop, do while loop and for-loop. However, the code seems to be incorrect.

```
class CompProject1 {

public static void main()

{

     int num;

     for(num=1; num<100; num++)

     {

         int sum = 0;

         for(int j = 1; j<=num ; j++)

         {

              if(num%j==0)

              {

               sum = sum+j;

              }

       }

       if(sum==num)

       {

        System.out.println(sum);  

        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class factors{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int sum=0;

    for(int k=2;k<=30;k++){
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(k%i==0)
            sum=sum+i;


    }
       if(k==sum)
             System.out.println(sum);


        sum=0;          //sum=0 is very important.
    }

}
```

}

**OUTPUT**

```
6
28
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PERFECT
 {
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
         int i,j,S,
          for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
          {
          S=0
          for(j=1;j<i;j++)
          {
          if(i%j==0)
           S+=j;
           if (S==i)
           System.out.println(i+"is perfect");
           }
           }
           }
           }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way of finding [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

- if **2<sup>p</sup>-1** is prime when **p** is prime. Then **(2<sup>p-1</sup>)(2<sup>p</sup>-1)** is a perfect number. **2<sup>p</sup>-1** is known as a [Mersenne Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Mersenne%20prime,so%20is%202n%20%E2%88%92%201)
- As these numbers get real big real fast, using [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) is recommended.

This computes the first 10 perfect numbers.

```
int N = 10;
int count = 1;
for(int i = 2; i < 10_000; i += i == 2 ? 1 : 2) {
    BigInteger val = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    if (val.isProbablePrime(99)) {
        BigInteger mersenne1 = (BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(i)).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        if (!mersenne1.isProbablePrime(99)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        BigInteger mersenne2 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(i-1);
        System.out.printf("%3d:  %,d\n",count, mersenne1.multiply(mersenne2));
       
        if (count++ >= N) {
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

prints

```
  1:  6
  2:  28
  3:  496
  4:  8,128
  5:  33,550,336
  6:  8,589,869,056
  7:  137,438,691,328
  8:  2,305,843,008,139,952,128
  9:  2,658,455,991,569,831,744,654,692,615,953,842,176
 10:  191,561,942,608,236,107,294,793,378,084,303,638,130,997,321,548,169,216
```